# Google Maps search - Map wont change focus from search input

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Hello fellow Stackoverflow members.

I have offered to help out our local communities emergency volunteer group with an improved alert map for notifying members of incidents close by to our town.
I have been using the google maps api, along with the google places api.

I have managed to bring in their news alert JSON data, match it with their custom icons, and display it on the map successfully. However I am now struggling to get the places searchBox to update the map based on the address users are entering into the search.

NB: The search is auto-completing fine, but the map is not updating. Current error is "map.fitBounds is not a function"

My reference link which I have been using to try and get the places search integrated: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/blob/737eb41e78f9cad28e2664b68450676e91424219/dist/samples/places-searchbox/inline.html

I have attached my code below. With a comment where I have added the latest edits to the code for the search function. A fresh perspective would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I have compiled a JSFiddle for easier handling:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcmacca002/zvghd0nu/

Thank you and appreciated.

```
// BUILD GOOGLE MAPS:
var GoogleMap = {
  map: null,
  markers: {},
  init: function(lat, lng, places) {
      var self = this;
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
      });

// SEARCH STARTS HERE (ALONG WITH ISSUES):
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
      google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        searchBox.set('map', null);
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
       (function(place) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

           position: place.geometry.location
         });
         marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
           if (!this.getMap()) {
             this.unbindAll();
           }
         });
         bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


       }(place));

     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     searchBox.set('map', map);
     map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));

   });
 
// END OF SEARCH HERE.
      
      
      $.each(places, function() {
          self.addMarker(this);
      });
      this.setCenterPoint();
  },

  
  
  // Create map markers
  addMarker: function(place) {
      var self = this;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude),
          map: self.map,
          title: place.name,
          icon: place.image
      });
      console.log(place);
  
  // Create information event for each marker
      marker.info_window_content = 'TEST'
      self.markers[place.id] = marker
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          self.infowindow.setContent(marker.info_window_content)
          self.infowindow.open(self.map, marker);
      });
  },

  // Update map markers
  updateMarkers: function(records) {
      var self = this;
      $.each(self.markers, function() {
          this.setMap(null);
      })
      $.each(records, function() {
          self.markers[this.id].setMap(self.map);
      });
      //Set map center
      if (records.length) self.setCenterPoint();
  },
  
  // Set centre point for map
  setCenterPoint: function() {
      var lat = 0,
          lng = 0;
      count = 0;
  
      //Calculate approximate center point based on number of JSON entries
      for (id in this.markers) {
          var m = this.markers[id];
          if (m.map) {
              lat += m.getPosition().lat();
              lng += m.getPosition().lng();
              count++;
          }
      }
      if (count > 0) {
          this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat / count, lng / count));
      }
  }
};
```

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div class="container" id="map" style="height:900px;"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the bounds and not the exact center position + zoom?

Comment: I was working from the google places documentation, which is the approach that they used: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Comment: Huh ok found another example where they used something like `setCenter()`. I guess you need to call `this.map.fitBounds(...)` instead of `map.fitBounds(...)`.

Comment: @MauriceNino have updated my post with the JSFiddle. LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/mcmacca002/zvghd0nu/

Thank you for trying to help. The fresh perspective is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error, because you have a wrong reference to `this`. I updated your Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k23auboq/ but I will also show you what went wrong down below.

```js
init: function(lat, lng, places) {
    // ... 

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', () => { // if you pass an arrow function here instead, 'this' will be taken from the outer context
        searchBox.set('map', null);
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var i, place;
        for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.geometry.location
            });
            marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
            if (!this.getMap()) {
                this.unbindAll();
            }
            });
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
        this.map.fitBounds(bounds); // this.map.fitBounds(...) now exists and works
        searchBox.set('map', map);
        this.map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(), 12));
    });

    // ... 
},
```

To simplify it a bit take a look at the following examples:

```js
function Test() {
  this.map = 'test map';
  
  this.callbackAction = function (callback) {
    callback();
  }
  
  this.action = function () {
    this.callbackAction(function () { // callback passed as 'function'
      console.log(this.map);
    });
  }
  
  return this;
}

const instance = new Test();
instance.action();
```

vs

```js
function Test() {
  this.map = 'test map';
  
  this.callbackAction = function (callback) {
    callback();
  }
  
  this.action = function () {
    this.callbackAction(() => { // callback passed as 'ARROW function'
      console.log(this.map);
    });
  }
  
  return this;
}

const instance = new Test();
instance.action();
```

Comment: I am not aware of any `map_changed` event.

Comment: Thank you @MauriceNino - greatly appreciated

Comment: Solution by Maurice is updating the map to the searched location. Zoom level isn't consistent with the level before the search is triggered. Possibly due to the latlong level search is using? I believe similar issue occurs in leaflet.js

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the answer which was provided above. The answer was technically correct, however using the bounds method will zoom the map down to level 1.

Here is a solution which should work for you. I have not been able to add a pin to the searched location. Hopefully somebody else may be able to help  you there as I have only applied what I have learned using leaflet.js which is slightly different to Google maps, and am only still learning Javascript.

```
var GoogleMap = {
    map: null,
    markers: {},
    init: function(lat, lng, places) {
        var self = this;
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            draggable: true
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            size: new google.maps.Size(10, 10)
        });
        // SEARCH STARTS HERE:
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', () => {
            searchBox.set('map', null);
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var i, place;
            for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                title: places.name,
                zoom: 4,
                position: place.geometry.location             
              });
              marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
                if (!this.getMap()) {
                  this.unbindAll();
                }
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
              });
              marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            }
            // ADDING PANTO FOR RETAINING THE MAP ZOOM LEVEL - INSTEAD OF SETZOOM :D
            this.map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

        });

        // WHICH THEN ENABLES YOU TO REMOVE THIS:
        // this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        // searchBox.set('map', map);
        // this.map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(), 12));
        
        // END OF SEARCH HERE.
```